# C++ error: Out of range: basic_string

Tags: c++, string, windows, text

I just started learning programming a few months ago and so far I haven't encountered any error that google search can't solve until this one.

This simple program asks the user for 3 inputs, movie name, sales of adult and child tickets. Then, displays the profit.

Every time I enter a number for the second and third inputs, I get the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type >std::out_of_range: basic_string

I am sorry if this question had been asked hundreds of time, but I can't seem to fix the problem myself.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int adultPrice= 12, childPrice= 6,
           adultSold, childSold,
           totalLength, theatreLength, disLength,
           totalLength2, theatreLength2, disLength2,
           totalProfit, theatreProfit, disProfit;

       const double theatre = 0.2;

       string movie,
              totalString, theatreString, disString;

       cout<<"This program calculates a theater's gross and net box office profit for a night."<< endl;
       cout<<"Which movie are you calculating? ";
       getline(cin,movie);

       cout<<"How many adult and children tickets were sold?(Please enter adult tickets first and separate by a space) ";
       cin>>adultSold>>childSold; \\ The number of tickets sold.

       totalProfit = adultSold * adultPrice + childSold * childPrice;
       theatreProfit = totalProfit * theatre;
       disProfit = totalProfit - theatreProfit;

       totalString = to_string(totalProfit);
       theatreString = to_string(theatreProfit);
       disString = to_string(disProfit);

       totalLength2 = totalLength = totalString.length();
       theatreLength2 = theatreLength = theatreString.length();
       disLength2 = disLength = disString.length();

       while(totalLength > 3)
       {
          totalLength -= 3;
          totalString.insert(totalLength, ",");
       }
       while(theatreLength > 3)
       {
          theatreLength -= 3;
          theatreString.insert(theatreLength, ",");
       }
       while(disLength > 3)
       {
          disLength -= 3;
          disString.insert(disLength, ",");
       }

       totalString.insert(totalLength2+1,".00");
       theatreString.insert(theatreLength2+1,".00");
       disString.insert(disLength2+1,".00");


       cout<<setw(30)<<"Movie Name: "<<setw(20)<<left<< movie <<endl;
       cout<<setw(30)<<"Adults tickets sold: "<<setw(20)<<left<< adultSold <<endl;
       cout<<setw(30)<<"Children tickets sold: "<<setw(20)<<left<< childSold <<endl;
       cout<<setw(30)<<"Gross Box Office Profit: "<<"$"<<setw(20)<<left<< totalString <<endl;
       cout<<setw(30)<<"Net Box Office Profit: "<<"$"<<setw(20)<<left<< theatreString <<endl;
       cout<<setw(30)<<"Amount Paid to Distributor: "<<"$"<<setw(20)<<left<< disString <<endl;


    }
```

Comment: So we have to guess where the error occurs?

Comment: I suggest using a Debugger and viewing the variables to all the string `insert` methods and verifying that they are within the bounds of the string.

Comment: Use a debugger, or in the least provide us  a line which you feel is causing the error. Often the line number that is causing the problem is specified in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these three lines to

```
    totalString.insert(totalLength2,".00");
    theatreString.insert(theatreLength2,".00");
    disString.insert(disLength2,".00");
```

This corrects your problem because in c++ the memory locations used to contain the internal string data are stored in indexed buckets which are numbered from zero to length -1 with an additional null terminator at the end.

If you try to reference the position at length +1 you are referencing a location which is outside of the bounds of the internal string storage area.

For example, given a c++ string with a value 'mystring'.

```
    string.c_str()[0] is equal to 'm'
    string.c_str()[string.length()] is equal to '\0'
    string.c_str()[string.length()+1] is undefined.
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with annotation about how your solution answers the OP's question or issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem lines of codes and also explaining why it's not working!